# Is it possible to write array without length to Parcel when the length is known?

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

Methods like `Parcel#readByteArray` tend to be used like this in examples I've seen:

```
byte[] _byte = new byte[in.readInt()]; 
in.readByteArray(_byte);
```

But there is no reason (that I see) to write this instead of

```
byte[] _byte = in.createByteArray();
```

It seems that `read*Array` is more useful when length is known in advance, but `write*Array` always writes the length. Is there a way to avoid writing it?